# Loading data in a Spatialite DB with custom CRS from QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, spatialite

I created a custom CRS in QGIS and proceeded to create a Spatialite database with layers using this custom CRS. In order to do this, I edited spatial_ref_sys and spatial_ref_sys_aux tables in the database and added my custom CRS. 
When I try to load data into this database using QSpatialite I get a Destination SRID isn't valid. 
Loading through the DB Manager succeeds but the table doesn't get an SRID. My only option to load data is by using the standalone Spatialite GUI which works perfectly fine.

So my question is: is there a workaround in order to be able to successfully load data from QGIS into a Spatialite database with a custom CRS?

*Note*: I haven't messed around with QGIS srs.db file.